# Tests for Authentication - Rails won't recognize signin method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been working through M. Hartl's tutorial on Rails and have reached a point where I cannot understand why my authentication tests won't pass.  My application works in every respect that it should at this point, and I'm wondering why the tests continue to fail.

I'm still quite new at Rails, please let me know if I can post any other elements to help make the situation more clear.

Stuart

Error Messages:

```
Failures:

1) Authentication signin with valid information 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
   expected css "title" with text "Stuart Culpepper" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:33:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) Authentication signin with valid information 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)) }
   expected link "Settings" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:35:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

3) Authentication signin with valid information 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
   expected link "Profile" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:34:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

4) Authentication signin with valid information 
 Failure/Error: it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }
   expected link "Sign in" not to return anything
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:37:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

5) Authentication signin with valid information 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
   expected link "Sign out" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:36:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My authentication Rspec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do
before { visit signin_path }

it { should have_selector( 'h1', text: 'Sign in' )}
it { should have_selector( 'title', text: 'Sign in' )}
  end

  describe "signin" do
before { visit signin_path }

  describe "with invalid information" do
    before { click_button "Sign in" }

    it { should have_selector( 'title', text: 'Sign in' )}
    it { should have_error_message('Invalid') }

    describe "after visiting another page" do
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_error_message( 'invalid')}
  end
 end

   describe "with valid information" do
     let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
     before { valid_signin(user) }

    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
    it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
    it { should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)) }
    it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
    it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

  describe "followed by signout" 
    before { click_link "Sign out" }
    it { should have_link('Sign in') }
  end
end

end
```

My Rrpec/Support/Utilities.rb

```
include ApplicationHelper

def valid_signin(user)
fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
fill_in "Password", with: user.password
click_button "Sign in"
end

RSpec::Matchers.define :have_error_message do |message|
match do |page|
    page.should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: message)
end
end

def sign_in(user)
  visit signin_path
  fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
  fill_in "Password", with: user.password
  click_button "Sign in"
  # Sign in when not using Capybara as well.
  cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end
```

Sessons Controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new
    @title = "Sign in"
end

def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        sign_in user
        redirect_to user
    else
        flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination"
        @title = "Sign in"
    render 'new'
  end
end

def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
end
end
```

Routes.rb

```
SampleApp3::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [ :new, :create, :destroy ]

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'  
end
```

app/views/sessions/new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign in") %>
<h1>Sign in</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">
            <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>

            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.text_field :email %>

            <%= f.label :password %>
            <%= f.text_field :password %>

            <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>

        <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %><p>
    </div>
</div>
```

app/spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
  end

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end
    end

    describe "after submission" do
        before { click_button submit }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign up') }
        it { should have_content('error') }
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      describe "after saving the user" do
        before { click_button submit }
        let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
        it { should have_link('Sign out') }
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end

  describe "edit" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit edit_user_path(user) }

  describe "page" do
    it { should have_selector( 'h1', text: "Update your profile" ) }
    it { should have_error_message('title', text: "Edit user") }
    it { should have_link( 'change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
  end

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Save changes" }

      it { should have_content( 'error' ) }
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: Can you paste app/views/sessions/new.html.erb?

Comment: Yes benjamin, sorry to have left the view out.

Comment: I also added the tests for user_pages_spec.rb

Comment: It looks like the user is not successfully signing in, so it's not redirecting to the user page. In your Authentication spec, find out if `FactoryGirl.create(:user)` is successfully creating a user, with `user.should be_valid` and let me know the result. The problem may be in your Factory setup.